# cast a char into a char* in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have a char array `s[11]="0123456789";` and I want to be able to take each digit `s[i]`(using a for loop) and cast it somehow to a `char*`(I need a char* specifically because I need to use strncat on some other string)

I've been trying to do this for the past 4 hours and I couldn't get anything done.

Comment: do `s+i` to get a `char*` at position `i`

Comment: If you want a pointer to character in the string, you can use `&s[i]`, which is equivalent to `(s+i)`.  If you want to cast the actual character into a pointer, as your post seems to indicate, you can use `(char *)s[i]`, although I can't imagine a useful purpose for doing so.

Comment: Note well that a pointer to the character at index `i` is not, in most cases, a pointer to a single-character string.  It is a pointer to the tail of `s` starting at that index.  This looks like an X-Y question.  I am reasonably confident that the real problem is that `strncat` is not the right tool for the job you're actually trying to perform.

Comment: If you'd tell us the context, e.g  the exact wording of the assignment, we wouldn't have to guess what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You do not want to "cast a char into a char *".  You are just trying to get the address of a char.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're willing to temporarily modify `s`, or copy the character somewhere else... You're going to have a hard time.

#### Modify `s` temporarily.

```
int main() {
  char s[11] = "0123456789";
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    // Modify s in place.
    const char tmp = s[i+1];
    s[i+1] = '\0';
    char *substr = &s[i];
    // Do something with substr.
    printf("%s\n", substr);
    // Fix s
    s[i+1] = tmp;
  }
}
```

#### Or copy `s[i]` to a new string.

```
int main() {
  char s[11] = "0123456789";
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    // Create a temporary string
    char substr[2];
    substr[0] = s[i];
    substr[1] = '\0';
    // Do something with substr.
    printf("%s\n", substr);
  }
}
```

## Or maybe just don't use strncat?

Assuming you're actually using `strncat` or similar... Those functions are pretty trivial, especially if you are appending only a single character. You might just create your own version.

```
void append_character(char *buffer, int buffer_size, char new_character) {
  int length = strlen(buffer);
  if (length + 2 < buffer_size) {
    buffer[length] = new_character;
    buffer[length+1]  = '\0';
  } else {
    // No space for an additional character, drop it like strncat would.
  }
}
```

Or you could do it as a simple wrapper around strncat:

```
void append_character(char *buffer, int buffer_size, char new_character) {
  char new_string[2] = { new_character, '\0' };
  strncat(buffer, buffer_size, new_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are requesting does not make any sense. A char is a small number. A pointer is the address of some memory. Converting a char to a pointer won't give you a valid pointer, but a pointer that will crash as soon as it is used.

For strncat, you need an array of characters containing a C string. You could create a string by writing char array[2]; (now you have an array with space for two characters), then array[0] = whateverchar; array[1] = 0; and now you have a C string with space for exactly one char and one trailing zero byte.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char src[11]="0123456789";
    char dest[50]="abc";

    char* p = src;
    int i = 0;
    int len = strlen(src);
    
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        strncat(dest,p,1);
        p++;
    }
    
    printf("src:  %s\n", src);
    printf("dest: %s\n", dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc under Ubuntu:

```
$ gcc hello_str.c -o hello_str
```

Output:

```
$ ./hello_str 
src:  0123456789
dest: abc0123456789
```